# How to Extract Larger Images from an HTML Page to Make Thumbnails (Like Facebook Does)

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, extract

In my application, I post articles and the entire document is stored as html in the database. In different places in the articles I use images. (By uploading it or just placing img urls).

On the homepage I want to make thumbnails of my desired size, so that I can place some recent articles along with their preview images there.

So, how can I extract larger images from any html document? (So that only relevant images are selected, not any other images)
And from the list of images, how to determine and select image which occurred at first?

I want to use that "one" image to make thumbnail programatically on the server. I
will cache it and then display it on the page.

Like a wordpress application or any other CMS does.

Currently, I use the following approach which is I think is not correct:
At the time of posting an article when I upload images in the editor, I keep the imageId of the of the last uploaded image and store it into the database along with the article. So I have a separate column for imageId for each article I post.

Problem starts when I do not upload any image, then I have to insert a default imageId automatically to avoid problems. This process is annoying. Please help me out. Please guide me the most practiced and the easiest solution available.

The site where I implement all this is http://disneyduniya.in

Answer (score 0):

You can use demo of below code: Generate Web Page Thumbnail Screenshot Image:

Demo link Its working : http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/07/C-Generate-WebPage-Thumbmail-Screenshot-Image

It will create image file ,save this file As and customize height and width 
.

Comment: Vishal sen This is not what I am looking for. The code you suggested takes screenshot of the page. I want to extract images, which I upload during I post a new article. When I make a new post, the article is stored as HTML in the database.